# emd2d function from emdist segfaults

Tags: r, list, crash, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to a list using apply but I'm having trouble doing so. I'm trying to calculate the earth-movers distance using the emdist package. Every index in the list has two subindices. I want to calculate the earth-movers distance for these subindices iteratively (the real list has thousands of indices). The problem is Rstudio crashes each time I try to run the code on a test dataset. An example of the test dataset:

```
set.seed(42) 
output1 <- list(list(matrix(0,8,11),matrix(0,8,11)), list(matrix(rnorm(80),8,10),matrix(rnorm(80),8,10))) 

[[1]] 
[[1]][[1]] 
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] 
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 

[[1]][[2]] 
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] 
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0 
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
```

Now when I do this:

```
library(emdist)
sapply(output1,function(x) {emd2d(x[[seq_along(x)[1]]],x[[seq_along(x)[2]]]) })
```

Rstudio simply crashes. I have also tried:

```
mapply(emd2d,sapply(output1,`[`,1),sapply(output1,`[`,2))
```

But to no avail. Any ideas? I'm running this on a 2013 macbook air with 2gb of RAM.

Comment: the line `seq_along(x)[1]` will ALWAYS result in the same value, 1...

Comment: Also, FWIW, I can run either of your code example successfully on Ubuntu from the console.

Comment: @Justin I get a segfault on OS X, from within the package's compiled C code. Regardless of whatever else is going on here, the segfault should be reported to the package author.

Comment: also a segfault here OS X, but I dont get what you think your doing with your code, your not providing the mats to the function

Comment: Same, the compiled C code crashes for me on OSX when I run `emd2d(output1[[1]][[1]]], output1[[1]][[2]])`. Regardless of the confusing use of `seq_along` in the post, it looks like this is an issue with the `emd2d` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works fine:

```
> emd2d(output1[[2]][[1]],output1[[2]][[2]])
[1] -6.089909
```

this does not:

```
emd2d(output1[[1]][[1]],output1[[1]][[2]])
```

Seems `emd2d()` might hate it when you compare *two all zero*  matrices...

At least for me on OSX as this succeeds for me:

```
set.seed(666)
output2 <- list(list(matrix(5,8,11),matrix(5,8,11)),  
           list(matrix(rnorm(80),8,10),matrix(rnorm(80),8,10)))
sapply(output2,function(x) {emd2d(x[[1]],x[[2]]) })
#[1]  0.000000 -7.995288
# not i removed your seq_along because I don't think you really want this..
```

as does this:

```
> set.seed(666)
> output2 <- list(list(matrix(0,8,11),matrix(5,8,11)), list(matrix(rnorm(80),8,10),matrix(rnorm(80),8,10)))
> sapply(output2,function(x) {emd2d(x[[1]],x[[2]]) })
[1]       NaN -7.995288
```

Maybe you need to contact the package creator about this then, in the mean time you could create a function that checks if both matrices are all zeros, e.g.

```
foo <- function(z){ if( sum(length(z[[1]][ z[[1]] != 0]),
                            length(z[[2]][ z[[2]] != 0]) ) > 0){
                        emd2d(z[[1]],z[[2]]) 
                    }else{ 
                      0 
                    }   
                  }

# i use length and subsetting, not just sum(), in case somehow 
# the two matrices sum to zero because you have minus values in them

> sapply(output1, foo)
[1]  0.000000 -6.089909
```

Comment: The first set of matrices succeede for me.  The result of the function is a `NaN`.

Comment: @ OP maybe this is something to tackle with the package creator then...? Although I suppose you could build in a condition for when you come up with two all zero matrices and just predict the answer...?

Comment: I will contact the package creator and forward him this thread. Thanks a lot for all of your help.